# Trackers on Roku

Tags: wireshark, roku, brightscript

We are trying to get the trackers on the proxy(wireshark) we are getting all the trackers and their information on the brightscript debug console. But, there there is no impression of trackers such as first, midpoint, third, complete quarterlies on the proxy.We have tried calling **AsyncGetToString()** but that too not seems to be a help as it doesn't displays all the urls.

Here is my code have a look and please help me to find what we are missing:

```
trackRequest=CreateObject("roUrlTransfer")
        if response.config.isGetAdsMapGeneratedForSession = true
              if campaign <> invalid and type(campaign) = "roAssociativeArray"
                print "impA: "; campaign.vastTrackers.impression
                For Each imp In campaign.vastTrackers.impression 
                   trackRequest.SetURL(imp)
                   trackRequest.GetToString()
                End For
           End if
    End if
```

Comment: Is the problem in printing campaign or trackRequest.GetToString?
Have you tried to create a new roUrlTransfer for each track request?

Comment: The problem in printing **`trackRequest.getToString()`**.  yes, I had declared the `roUrlTransfer` in a global function, and then calling it again for `trackRequest`. That didn't solved my problem in-fact on the debug console there was not difference.

Comment: If `imp` is a valid url, make sure **GET** is the proper http verb for this request or it won't work. Then, be sure that request returns **data** (so that you can print it on console).
Note: If the request is https, you need to init certificates first.

Comment: Can you suggest me or provide me some examples

Comment: The url string and method can be tested with any api test tool (eg: postman). To initialise certificates use: `trackRequest.SetCertificatesFile("common:/certs/ca-bundle.crt")` and `trackRequest.InitClientCertificates()`

Comment: @Roberto14 **GET** is valid http verb. we are hitting this in a loop, and not getting response.

Comment: did you tried same urls on postman? Do they return valid responses?  If they do, Im running out of ideas.. :/